# C# FileSystemWatcher not triggering correctly in Service

Tags: c#, service, filesystemwatcher

I'm working on a service where in my `OnStart`method I have the following lines of code to set up my `FileSystemWatcher`

```
Log.Info($"File location {_location}");
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_location);      
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

Then in my `OnChanged` method I am wanting to start a timer like so:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Log.Info($"A file has been placed in {_location} starting timer");
    OnTimer(null, null); //run immediately at startup
    StartEventTimer();
}
```

The timer code works, so I know that isn't an issue, likewise in my log I know it is checking for the correct location. What is it that I'm missing?

All I'm wanting my code to do is to trigger my timer, the moment a file is placed in my target location yet I've not been able to do so. Am I correct in that I should be using `FileSystemWatcher`to do this, or should I use something else as this code is within a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things it could be based on what you said there.

The first thing of note is that the declaration for `var watcher` looks like it's not a class variable and will go out of scope when it exits `OnStart()`. You'll need to move the declaration outside of that.

The second item of interest is that it looks like `EnableRaisingEvents` isn't being set. A working example of the `FileSystemWatcher` is below.

```
public class SomeService
{
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
    public void OnStart()
    {
        // set up the watcher
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_location);
        _watcher.Path = path;
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        _watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        _watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

As Ben Hall mentioned, it is possible that multiple events can be raised for the same file when a file is moved into the folder. As per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher#Anchor_6);

> Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised. Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher

Comment: This has the risk of it firing twice see my answer below. [Gist demonstrating it firing twice](https://gist.github.com/benbhall/ec6e6264fa6d4386908139ab521a7835) and a [Gist demonstrating single fire on file create using Created and NotifyFilter.FileName](https://gist.github.com/benbhall/b2b4abcc0df20571ed0a17a0b65fce0d)

Answer (score 1):

You might well find that the Changed event is firing more than once on a new file, a common problem with some applications, which might create unwanted side effects later on. Have a look and try changing to Created instead.

If you're looking for a new file appearing in a folder, you should use:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
watcher.Created += OnCreated;
```

[Gist demonstrating it firing twice using Changed on LastWrite](https://gist.github.com/benbhall/ec6e6264fa6d4386908139ab521a7835) and a for predictable behaviour, a [Gist demonstrating single fire on file create using Created and NotifyFilter.FileName](https://gist.github.com/benbhall/b2b4abcc0df20571ed0a17a0b65fce0d)

Just run it up in a Console App and copy a file into c:\temp.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote but I'd be interested in seeing an explanation as to the duplicate firing. The code examples given don't look like they'd fire twice unless a file was created/changed twice

Comment: Multiple events is a known issue mentioned in a few places e.g. bottom of [MSDN FileSystemWatcher class page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher). I had to experiment extensively for some work I've just completed, to handle new files in a folder. The Gists when run, and a file copied into a folder, will demonstrate such a scenario. It is to do with the way the OS and some applications behave. We buffered events through MemoryCache in the end just as a safety net over the possibility but Created with NotifyFilters.FileName has proven solid so far.

Comment: Good to know! You may want to include that detail in your answer though. I suspect that was the reason for your downvote, that it came across as "multiple events get raised, try this code", with no follow up explanation or detail - and SO thrives on detail :) I'll upvote as the info was accurate and I wasn't aware of it myself until you raised it